# Wine is taking way too long to unpack

Tags: software-installation, wine, dpkg

It has been stuck on this for hours:

[image: screenshot]

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It seems to be an issue with dpkg, but I am not sure how to fix it. I know this isn't a lot of information, but I don't know what else to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out on my own.

I just ended up removing the package using

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r wine-stable-i386:i386
```

And I was able to move on with installing any other packages without dpkg trying to annoy me about updating it. I'm not sure how to properly install it, but that should at least help anyone who keeps having dpkg annoy them with bad packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any anti-virus software, just disable it or uninstall it.

I had Sophos Antivirus and it blocked the instalation of Wine for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be due to a slow hard disk, or a full RAM as well so I suggest you check that out as well.
If you face the same issue in some other hardware then let me know. For now try creating a new user and try installing again, and then we can know if there were some other issues in the main user...

Comment: Hey dg_linux! Please refer the other answers provided by PokemonFan011(the user who asked this question).